# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.safari.pushNotification')

Tags: javascript, ios, push-notification, safari

I'm using pusher (https://github.com/pusher/push-notifications-web) for web notifications. The push notifications work on safari desktop but not on mobile iOS with a home screen app. From iOS 16.4 on Safari allows push notifications when it's a home screen app. I use 2.0.0-beta.2 for the notifications. I guess pusher is just not ready yet for iOS push notifications. Is there something I can do so that the push notifications work with a home screen app?

I expect that I can register the device on iOS like in the desktop safari.

```
function startpush() {
  beamsClient.start().then(() => beamsClient.getDeviceId())
    .then(deviceId => {
      console.log(deviceId)
      localStorage.setItem('push-l', 'set')
      // $('#activate').hide();
      $('#steps-mobile').hide();
    })
    .catch(e => console.error('Could not get device id', e));
}
```